# org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of --- in shared preference android

Tags: android, json, sharedpreferences

Here is my code. in this I'm retrieving json data stored as string in shared preference.
but instead I'm getting exception which is below.
 now the thing is I have tried to print out "`String fav`" 3 times but it just omit that `Log.i` and doesn't print it. So I can't figure out what is the problem.. Please help me out.. thnx in advance

```
public class RetriveData {  

static public void savefavRetailer() {

    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
    if (Perma.favRetailer.isEmpty()) {
        jArray.put(Perma.followerId);
    } else {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < Perma.favRetailer.size(); i++) {
                jArray.put(Perma.favRetailer.get(i));
            }
            jArray.put(Perma.favRetailer.size(), Perma.followerId);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Perma.editor.putString("favRetailer", jArray.toString());
    Perma.editor.putString("favRetailer " + Perma.followerId, Perma.followerName);
    Perma.editor.commit();
}

static public void removefavRetailer() {
    Perma.favRetailer.remove(Perma.followerId);
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(Perma.favRetailer);
    Perma.editor.putString("favRetailer", jArray.toString());
    Perma.editor.commit();
}




static ArrayList<String> getfavRetailer() {
    String fav ;
    Log.i("I getArrayofRetailer", "In");
    Log.i("I getArrayofRetailer", "In");
    fav= Perma.sharedPref.getString("favRetailer", "");

    Log.i("REtrive Data fav",""+fav);
    if (fav != null) {
        Log.i("REtrive Data 2ndfav",""+fav);    
        try {
            Log.i("REtrive Data 3rdfav",""+fav);
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(fav);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                String temp = jArray.optString(i);
                Perma.favRetailer.add(temp);
            }
            Log.i("I getArrayofRetailer", "jArray " + jArray.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.i("getArrayofRetailer", "Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return Perma.favRetailer;
}

}
```

Here is log. now in this I'm getting log only three times  ???

```
04-29 11:11:33.165: I/I getArrayofRetailer(882): In
04-29 11:11:33.165: I/I getArrayofRetailer(882): In
04-29 11:11:33.176: I/getArrayofRetailer(882): Exception

04-29 11:11:33.184: W/System.err(882): org.json.JSONException: End of input at  character 0 of 
04-29 11:11:33.184: W/System.err(882):  at    org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:446)
04-29 11:11:33.194: W/System.err(882):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:93)
04-29 11:11:33.194: W/System.err(882):  at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:87)
04-29 11:11:33.194: W/System.err(882):  at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
04-29 11:11:33.194: W/System.err(882):  at rensoft.connectyfinal.RetriveData.getfavRetailer(RetriveData.java:34)
04-29 11:11:33.194: W/System.err(882):  at rensoft.connectyfinal.Inbox.onCreate(Inbox.java:52)
04-29 11:11:33.194: W/System.err(882):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-29 11:11:33.214: W/System.err(882):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-29 11:11:33.214: W/System.err(882):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-29 11:11:33.214: W/System.err(882):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-29 11:11:33.214: W/System.err(882):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-29 11:11:33.214: W/System.err(882):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-29 11:11:33.214: W/System.err(882):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-29 11:11:33.224: W/System.err(882):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-29 11:11:33.224: W/System.err(882):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 11:11:33.224: W/System.err(882):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-29 11:11:33.224: W/System.err(882):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-29 11:11:33.224: W/System.err(882):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-29 11:11:33.234: W/System.err(882):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: {
    "message":"something",
    "type":"news",
    "id":"32"
    }   but at app start user doesnt have saved any data so its going to return null.

Comment: post RetriveData.java and mention line no 34.

Comment: try to change if (fav != null) to (null!=fav). I know its silly, but it works in some cases.

Comment: @rajeshwaran  JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(fav);   This is line 34

Comment: in log "fav" string is print value ?

Comment: @rajeshwaran  in log i'm printing string fav. but its omiting that line,,

Comment: "if (fav != null)" is not needed. It cannot be null at this point, because you use "" as fallback value for getString. Your json fav is a JsonObject, not an Array.

Comment: @luxer thnx for pointing out this was a silly mistake

Comment: If you use eclipse, did you tried debugging your application put a breakpoint at method entry and step over your method?

Comment: @luxer sorry but i dont know how to do that.. can you point out some good tutorial..

Comment: You can find many tutorials, just try searching for it. Your exception is logical if fav = "". It isn't anything jsonlike so it can't be parsed. About your omitted logs you can propably check it out by debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line `if (fav != null) {` to `if (fav.length() == 0) {`.

`fav= Perma.sharedPref.getString("favRetailer", "");` returns an empty string if the "favRetailer" item doesn't exist in your SharedPreferences, so you have to check for an empty string instead of null before parsing the json.